# Update the view of two forms, sharing a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

## Problem:

I need to have two (or more) form instances that share the same form controls group, and changing the values from one form should update the UI of the other forms.

I.e. if I have two forms containing one dropdown, and a user selects a value through one of the the dropdowns it should automatically update the view of the respective dropdown in the other form.

**It works fine if I update it programmatically** via `patchValue` for example, the views of both dropdowns get updated.

**It fails if its done from the UI**. It only updates the value of the dropdown the user interacted with, even though the underlying form control model is updated successfully. (???!?)

A workaround I found was to use `ngModel` directive alongside the `formControlName` directive, but I feel that I shouldn't need to do this.

### Oversimplified example:

Let's say I've got the following form group, defined in *myService*

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    selection: new FormControl('')
});
```

component template that **doesn't work**:

```
<form [formGroup]="myService.myForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="selection">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
            {{ option.label }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

component template that **WORKS**:

```
<form [formGroup]="myService.myForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select
          formControlName="selection"
          [ngModel]="myService.myForm.controls['selection'].value"
        >
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
            {{ option.label }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: Don't use ngModel with reactiveForm, just pick one

Comment: @WindomEarle please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: @NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-example-fxfx9a 

Changing 1 dropdown doesn't change the other dropdown, even though the underlying form control is updated and both dropdowns use the same form control.

The stackblitz environment is using Angular 5, but I'm having the same issue in Angular 15

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the stackblitz. I added a listener that will call patch value manually, that fixed the issue, hope it helps you!

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    selection: new FormControl('a'),
  });

  options = [
    { label: 'Option A', value: 'a' },
    { label: 'Option B', value: 'b' },
    { label: 'Option C', value: 'c' },
    { label: 'Option D', value: 'd' },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const selectionCtrl = this.myForm.get('selection');
    if (selectionCtrl) {
      selectionCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        selectionCtrl.patchValue(selectionCtrl.value, { emitEvent: false });
      });
    }
    // you can try this code also, it works for the entire form!
    // if (this.myForm) {
    //   this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    //     this.myForm.patchValue(this.myForm.value, { emitEvent: false });
    //   });
    // }
  }
}
```

html

```
Form #1
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="selection" id="selection" name="selection">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{ option.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Form #2
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="selection" id="selection" name="selection">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{ option.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

<pre>Selection: {{ myForm.controls.selection.value }}</pre>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-example-xik8zs)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this happens with mat-select? Cuz it seems to work out of the box when used with a native select element, without needing to subscribe to valueChanges and patching the value manually.

Comment: @WindomEarle Usually one form will have only one html form structure, so its intuitive to work this way, but still there is a work around!